Is it possible to edit a mask layer without detaching it in inkscape?
I have a rectangle with a gray gradient that serves as a mask in Inkscape.
To change the gradient position, I detach the mask, move the gradient handlers and re-attach the rectangle as a mask.
Can I modify the gradient handlers in Inkscape without having to detach-reattach each time?

Not directly. The mask isn't selectable or editable once it is applied to an object. However, you could keep your mask object off the page, create a clone of it, and use the clone as the mask.  Then if you edit the gradient handles on the clone source, the cloned mask will be updated automatically.
A simple example


Humm... Didn't know about the "clone" thing. So it's like creating an "alias" that replicates the original's parameters?

Yes.  A clone can also be a group of objects. If you make a lot of clones, you can edit the clone source and all the clones will update.
